# Shorthand React prop causing reference error with transform-react-constant-elements Babel plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I am having an issue only on production and getting `ReferenceError: _ref7 is not defined` error. 
I can also reproduce the issue on local when I change this line:

```
isProduction ? "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements" : null,
```

to this:

```
"@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements",
```

in my babel.config.js file.

Apparently the issue is caused by the `transform-react-constant-elements` Babel plugin during the rendition of the component below:

```
// This gives error
return (
  <EntityRoute
    backToRoot={backToRoot}
    levels={levels}
    manyToManyRelation
  />
);
```

I tried a few things to fix this and the solution worked for me was not using a shorthand prop and use it like this:

```
// This works
const manyToManyRelation = true;

return (
  <EntityRoute
    backToRoot={backToRoot}
    levels={levels}
    manyToManyRelation={manyToManyRelation}
  />
);
```

I would at least expect below one would also work, but it doesn't.

```
// This fails
return (
  <EntityRoute
    backToRoot={backToRoot}
    levels={levels}
    manyToManyRelation={true}
  />
);
```

I wonder why the last one doesn't work. 
Thanks.

UPDATE: 
Below you can find my babel configuration and the version numbers:

babel.config.js

```
/* eslint-env node */
"use strict";

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const isDevelopment = mode === "development";
const isProduction = mode === "production";
const isTest = mode === "test";

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      isTest
        ? {
            targets: {
              node: "current", // Overrides .browserslistrc
            },
          }
        : {
            corejs: { version: 3, proposals: true },
            loose: true, // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4263
            modules: false,
            useBuiltIns: "entry",
          },
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        development: isDevelopment,
        useBuiltIns: true,
      },
    ],
    "@babel/preset-flow",
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      "babel-plugin-module-resolver",
      {
        alias: {
          src: "./src",
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator",
      {
        async: false, // Done by @babel/preset-env
      },
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        helpers: false,
        useESModules: true,
      },
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    isDevelopment ? "react-hot-loader/babel" : null,
    isProduction ? "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements" : null,
    isProduction
      ? [
          "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types",
          {
            removeImport: true,
          },
        ]
      : null,
    isProduction
      ? [
          "babel-plugin-react-intl",
          {
            messagesDir: "build/messages",
          },
        ]
      : null,
  ].filter(plugin => plugin !== null),
};
```

Babel related parts from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.7.4",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
  "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
  "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
  "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^4.1.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
  ...
}
```

Comment: could be a preset thing. Can you share your babel.config.js file and also the babel versions you are using

Comment: Hi @Rain.To I added the babel configuration and the babel related dependency versions.

Answer (score -1):

You have a lot going on with customization's. To me your preset should be like below to let babel default configurations do the work for you in a way they recommend in their roadmap. but yes again if you need to customize it , you do.

```
 presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      isTest
        ? {
            targets: {
              node: "current", // Overrides .browserslistrc
            },
          }
        : {
            corejs: { version: 3, proposals: true },
            useBuiltIns: "usage",
          },
    ],

    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-flow",
  ]
```

And then in plugin remove this whole line

```
isProduction ? "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements" : null,
```

run a local test and see if that helps , we do write the code the way you had mentioned earlier and don't have to declare a bool variable to pass on as property.